# Regular Expression: convert a list of name and value pairs to query string

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, coldfusion, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, lucee

I am working on an URL rewrite with Lucee/Tomcat and the [Tuckey plugin](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). To simplify the problem: I need a regular expression that converts a list delimited by colons, to a regular url query string format.

For example, convert this

```
one1:aaa:two2:bbb:three3:ccc
```

into this:

```
one1=aaa&two2=bbb&three3=ccc
```

The list length may vary. The parameter names and their values are alpha-numeric.

Ideally, I would like to replace every odd numbered occurrence of the delimiter `:` with a `=`, and replace even numbered occurrences with `&`.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean replace odd and even occurrences of the list delimiter `:`? ie. `one1(odd)aaa(even)two2(odd)bbb(even)three3(odd)ccc`

Comment: Yes thats what I have meant, like the example I showed.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at something like this.

`(\w+):(\w+):?` and replace with `$1=$2&` and then just strip the final ? of in a second command.

See my work
https://regex101.com/r/7nh1Mb/1

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it looks so simple but i tried it more compcliate.
It seems that there is a conditional function for regex, but it is not appropriable  for substitutions to eliminate the last ampersand (&). 
Example: `(?(?=regex)then|else)`
If $1 and $2 length greater 0, then put a "&" at the end into it.